# What does "getting rinsed" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I saw this [tweet](https://twitter.com/jrhennessy/status/815510569293737984)

[image]

> WATCH: 3-YR-OLD CHESS PRODIGY CRIES AFTER GETTING RINSED ON RUSSIAN TV

and couldn't make sense of it, my mother tongue not being English did not help the situation, thus I'm here... Thanks for answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is British slang and it means he was beaten badly. Humiliated, ruined, destroyed.

As [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rinse) says (meaning 3):

> **rinse** (*v.*) (Britain, slang) To thoroughly defeat in an argument, fight or other competition.

Comment: It's not a use that I have ever encountered before. Only by context could I guess the intended meaning.

Comment: Never heard "rinsed" before but seems tame compared to a similar expression "getting hosed" which in a competitive situation means "to lose badly".